# How can I identify the new Xbox 360 controller in stores?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

The new Xbox 360 controller is starting to become available in local stores, at least I think so.

Is there any way I can identify the new controller, either by looks or a serial number or something?

I've seen pictures of it, and it looks like it has a new silver finish, and uncolored buttons, is this the only controller that has those features?

Basically I'd like to know how I can identify it so that I can avoid purchasing an old controller and not discover it until I get home and can open it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can identify it by looking at the new d-pad, and easier way might be to look at the colors. The new controller is entirely made up of shades of gray. I think this is the only controller where the buttons aren't the standard colors.

Amazon categorizes the controller under [silver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0041HROGG), so that might help you identify it as well (although I don't recall if the packaging lists it as silver or not).

Comment: When I purchased mine, the package was see through.  As a result you could visually see the controller was silver.  There are only know silver Xbox 360 controllers (unless I'm mistaken); this one and the [Halo Reach special](http://i.imgur.com/Mxrhl.jpg) controller.  The Reach controller has additional Silver accents which this one does not.  Additionally, the Reach controller has Red, Green, Blue, Yellow buttons, as compared to grey buttons

Comment: @tzenes Plus the Halo Reach controller will have Halo Reach on the packaging quite a bit. I don't think that it has the new d-pad, though.

Comment: no it does not, which is why its important to tell the difference between the two silver controllers

Answer (score 5):

It is a silver controller as mentioned by others and the D-Pad is distinctive. The box it comes in is also labeled as "Special Edition" and also includes mention of the Play & Charge Kit which is not standard with all of the wireless controllers. A view of the packaging can be seen below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think the key thing to keep an eye out for visually is the new transforming d-pad. On the old controllers this was one solid lump of plastic but on the new ones you can twist it to raise the position of the up, down, left and right arrows.

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering if it was easy to see that it had that new function. Perhaps the package is labelled.

Comment: It's easy to see because the new D-pad is 2-tone grey with chrome for the actual cross.

Answer (score 2):

The new controller is marked as "[Silver](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0041HROGG)" in most online catalogs. The package is transparent, so you can see the entire controller when you shop for it on store shelves. Look for all grey-shaded buttons (instead of the normal red, blue, green, and yellow) and the chrome D-Pad set inside the darker plastic ring.